# Event based read and output file lines

Tags: javascript, node.js, event-handling

In the near future, the app will have to start several actions after having read the content of the file (executing request based on the `request` module). I was wondering if this beginning makes sense, or if it should be written differently (it's my first app, so any advice is welcomed).

```
var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter
var jeu = new EventEmitter()
jeu.on('readFile', function(msg) {
  var lineReader = require('readline').createInterface({
    input: require('fs').createReadStream(msg)
  })

  lineReader.on('line', function (line) {
    jeu.emit('outputLines', line)
  })
})

jeu.on('outputLines', function(line) {
  console.log(line);
})

jeu.emit('readFile', 'liste.txt')
```

Comment: Why not just subclass the lineReader object, respond to the `line` method and then emit your own message after processing each line.  There's really no reason to create a whole new `EventEmitter` and duplicate everything.